# Pull properties from an object by their name into a different object

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

i'm doing a project in VueJS and i have an array of data, which consists of a number of objects.

These objects are pulled from a PHP Backend and consist of values like

id: 2123
name: "Name Value"
status: "active"
account_id: "2KGGALS2353255"

Imagine i want to split these by the keys names into a similar array but i want to have a parent object that consists of two child objects

```
[
    0: {
     core: {
       id: 2123
       name: "Name Value"
     },
     extra: {
       status: "active",
       account_id: "2KGGALS2353255" 
     }
]
```

The question is how can i achieve this with Javascript? I don't really want to modify the data in PHP beforehand unless this is something very unadvised to do in Javascript.
I can use VueJS and Lodash.

Comment: Could you put a before ->  after of what you want ? I think it's gonna be clearer

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for lodash's `pick()` method.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your purpose

```js
function separate(obj, keys) {
  let target = {}, rest = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if (keys.includes(key)) {
      target[key] = obj[key];
    } else {
      rest[key] = obj[key];
    }
  });
  return { target: target, rest: rest };
}

let stuff = { 
  id: 2123,
  name: "Name Value",
  status: "active",
  account_id: "2KGGALS2353255" 
};

let separated = separate(stuff, ['id', 'name']);

console.log({
  core: separated.target,
  extra: separated.rest
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6's [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), and the [object rest spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) proposal, which requires a [babel transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/), you can `Array#map` the array into a new array of objects in the required format:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"name":"Name1","status":"active","account_id":"2KGGALS2353255"},{"id":2,"name":"Name2","status":"active","account_id":"4ABCLS2353255"},{"id":3,"name":"Name3","status":"active","account_id":"6LMNALS2353255"}];

const result = arr.map(({ id, name, ...extra }) => ({
  core: {
    id,
    name
  },
  extra
}));

console.log(result);
```

You can do the same thing using lodash's [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) to the get the **core**, and [`_.omit()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) to get the **extra**:

```js
var arr = [{"id":1,"name":"Name1","status":"active","account_id":"2KGGALS2353255"},{"id":2,"name":"Name2","status":"active","account_id":"4ABCLS2353255"},{"id":3,"name":"Name3","status":"active","account_id":"6LMNALS2353255"}];

var result = arr.map(function(obj) {
  return {
    core: _.pick(obj, ['id', 'name']),
    extra: _.omit(obj, ['id', 'name'])
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```